# Добавление записей в связанные таблицы типизированного dataset

Tags: c#, ado.net, typed-dataset

Добрый день всем, я только начинаю разбираться ado.net и вроде бы всё хорошо и красиво работает, но не всё....

Создал я подключение к бд, автоматически создался типизированный датасет, есть две связанные таблицы по внешнему ключу, я их обе перетягиваю на форму, создаются датагриды и всё прекрасно отбражается и редактируется, засада когда я добавляю строки в обе таблицы, добавление не происходит, а вместо этого ошибка

Конфликт инструкции INSERT с ограничением FOREIGN KEY, такое ощущение что после вставки в первую таблицу ADO не подхватывает её новый ID, а записи из второй таблицы вставляет со ссылкой по временному ID

То есть в таблице 1 я создаю строку, затем в дочерней таблице создаю строки связанные с 1 и при сохранении ошибка.

### T1

### ID|name|

### T2

### id|order|idT1|

разве типизированный датаСет не должен сам решать такие проблемы? Как с этим бороться?
субд SQL Express 2014

Comment: А ошибка потому что при добавлении строки во вторую таблицу связанная с ней строка в первой таблице физически не существует и существовать она не будет до момента вызова Вами метода AcceptChanges() на датасете

Comment: И кстати, Вы же вкурсе, что все ваши изменения назад в базу не попадут?

Comment: да в курсе, но я сохраняю так:
`tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.PLANDataSet)`

Answer (score 1):

Тем временем, меня озарило и я нашёл ответ, и оно работает.

Было
[image: было]

Стало
[image: Стало]

Причём в БД все эти отношения прописаны, почему-то атоматически не пернеслись в датасет